# How to fill the visualcounter countdown counter?

Tags: context, visualcounter

I am trying to fill a `countdown` counter in order to get something like that

[image]

But, I did not manage to get it

```tex
\usemodule[visualcounter]

\startTEXpage
  \usevisualcounter[n=0,last=4,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=1,last=4,heigth=20pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=2,last=4,heigth=20pt,width=15pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=2,last=4,heigth=20pt,width=20pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=3,last=4,heigth=20pt,width=15pt,maxtext=0pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=3,last=4,heigth=20pt,width=0pt,maxtext=0pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
  \usevisualcounter[n=3,last=4,heigth=20pt,width=20pt,maxtext=20pt,distance=0pt]{countdown}
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

I assume this might be that I do not understand how to use `maxtext` and the [documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adityam/visualcounter/master/visualcounter.pdf) did not really helped me with this one.

Comment: You cannot do this with `countdown`. Both text and maxtext are the supposed to be strings. So, you would say something like `text=4, maxtext=40` to reserve to spaces for the text. But it is simple to generate a new counter which has the look of what you want. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively simple to define your own counters. This is one attempt which draws everything with a single color (I use `past_color`).

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]

\startuseMPgraphic{visualcounter::fullcircle}
  begingroup ;

  \includeMPgraphic{visualcounter::initialization}

  newnumeric diameter ;
  diameter := max(width, height) ;

  newpath inner_circle;
  % make the circle start at 12 o'clock and go clockwise 
  inner_circle := reverse (fullcircle scaled diameter) rotated 90;

  % step size
  newnumeric inner_time;
  inner_time := arclength (inner_circle)/last_counter ;

  newpath slice ;

  newpair start_pt, stop_pt;

  start_pt := point 0 on inner_circle;
  stop_pt  := point(current_counter*inner_time) on inner_circle;

  slice := inner_circle cutbefore start_pt cutafter stop_pt
     --- origin --- cycle ;

  draw inner_circle withpen pencircle scaled rulethickness withcolor past_color;
  fill slice withcolor past_color ;

  endgroup ;

\stopuseMPgraphic

\definevisualcounter
  [fullcircle]
  [         
    mp=visualcounter::fullcircle,
    width=2cm,
    height=2cm,
    rulethickness=4bp,
  ]

\starttext

\usevisualcounter[n=1,last=10]{fullcircle}
\usevisualcounter[n=3,last=10]{fullcircle}
\usevisualcounter[n=5,last=10]{fullcircle}
\usevisualcounter[n=7,last=10]{fullcircle}
\usevisualcounter[n=9,last=10]{fullcircle}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]